# Meaning of word "Teller"

Tags: meaning

Does the word "teller" in the meaning of "someone who tells something" mean that the person is quite likely to be a liar?

Comment: *And, while a lie has been told, the teller is not yet a liar.* Another example in the same dictionary.

Comment: Is "a teller of tales" a liar? That's no different from any author of fiction.

Comment: "Teller" clearly means the exact opposite of "liar", as nobody at all would ever pay a fortune liar.

Comment: @Tim Frat "teller" can also mean "bank cashier"...or *ATM," depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

Teller, in the sense we are talking about, simply means 'one who tells'. There is no suggestion of falsehood. The expression 'truth-teller' is common, and 'teller of truths' almost as common.

In the phrase "teller of tales" it is the *tales* part that has the suggestion of falsehood, not the *teller* part.

Comment: For instance, in "Terrapin Station", "The storyteller makes no choice
 soon you will not hear his voice
 his job is to shed light
 and not to master


Since the end is never told
 we pay the teller off in gold
 in hopes he will come back
 but he cannot be bought or sold"

Answer (score 0):

*Teller* means someone who counts. Compare it with Norwegian. As an example in that language take the title of a book which was published a few years ago *[Teller matte?](http://www.math.ntnu.no/abel/bok/)* which translates to *Does maths count?*

Comment: If you claim it has that meaning in English, you need a citation.

Comment: It does have this meaning, but it also means someone who tells, in the usual sense of 'tell'. The latter is clearly what the question is asking about.